# Building Boost with ICU using MinGW

Tags: c++, boost, build, mingw, icu

I downloaded the last ICU release (49) binaries and add the following arg to b2:

```
-sICU_PATH="D:\lib64\icu"
```

I got

```
gcc.link D:\boost\1.51.0\boost\boost\bin.v2\libs\locale\build\gcc-mingw-4.7.1\debug\has_icu64.exe                 
d:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -licui18n 
d:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -licudata 
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

There were not such libicui18n, libicudata among icu binaries.

So I tried to build it myself. I got this error

```
PATH=../../lib:../../stubdata:../../tools/ctestfw:$PATH  ../../bin/genrb -e UTF-8 -s resources -d uconvmsg root.txt                                                                                                                 
Makefile:173: recipe for target `uconvmsg/root.res'     failed                                                        
make[2]: *** [uconvmsg/root.res] Error 127
```

Could somebody suggest me how I should build Boost with ICU using MinGW?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.) the libraries in the package you downloaded are named `icuin49.dll`, `icudt49.dll`. We build regularly with mingw  (and many other platforms) to test, but don't post those binaries.

2.) uconv is just an extra. You can disable it with `--disable-extras` on the configure line. (not enough info there to tell me why it failed.)

Comment: This means that boost's config script has a bug, because it looks for i18n and data rather than in and dt? I'm hitting the same case

Comment: It’s possible the names are different between msvc and mingw (makefile) builds.